# Reg - Card present payment gateway integration

Tags: paypal

Can we use paypal payflow gateway for card present payment integration

From the documentation we noted that this is not supported if we have business in countries like India

This ref link https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf - says that 
SWIPE (card-present) transactions are not supported by the PayPal processor - what is this mean

Not able to find clear documentation for this - like how this works

Is any other payment gate way supports card present integration (for having business in India and Nigeria)

Please suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are some processors that support transmission of the raw card data.  Payflow can be configured to work with a number of different credit card processors -- including PayPal (via the PayPal Payments Pro or Website Payments Pro Payflow Edition products) -- and whether you can transmit the raw card data depends on which processor you are working with.  Most processors will accept the raw card data; however, the PayPal processor does not.

However, please note that Payflow Pro is only available in the United States, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand.  PayPal does not have any products at this time that will let a business in India process "card present" transactions.